# Akka group messages into pools

Tags: java, java-8, akka

I am trying to understand AKKA 2.10 specifically with Java (No Scala). I understand that concurrent patterns etc are much more expressive in Scala but I'd like for my samples to work in Java.

In particular I have a few actors which produces messages. A "BreadRollActor" produces breads, a "BaconActor" produces bacons, a "SaladActor" produces salads. I now have a BurgerAssemblyActor which receives "messages" viz Bacon, BreadRoll, Salad. I would like to combine 2 BreadRoll messages, 1 Bacon message and 10 Salad message into one Burger. How can this be best implemented in Akka Java as an actor.

```
public class Burger extends UntypedActor {

    private final LoggingAdapter LOG = Logging.getLogger(context().system(), this);

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if(message instanceof Bacon){
            LOG.info("Received Bacon");
            //Possibly add to a queue?
        }
        else if(message instanceof BreadRoll){
            LOG.info("Received BreadRoll");
            //Possibly add to a queue?
        }
        else if(message instanceof Salad){
            LOG.info("Received Salad");
            //Possibly add to a queue?
        }

    }
}
```

A typical Java developer mindset is to add them to a queue and then run another task to pick up 2 bread rolls, 1 burger and 10 salads, make a burger and put them for another actor. However that means I take control of the concurrency but I am assuming that is not the point of akka? How does akka help me here? I am reading concepts like FSM actors etc but it is now clear to me how I can apply that so some sample code answers will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd declare some variables that contain the needed quantities; then, when a messages arrives, I'd increment them and then I'd check if I can make a burger. When the condition is met, remember to subtract the needed values, so that the actor can work correctly even if the ingredients arrive in random order:

```
public class Burger extends UntypedActor {

    private static int NEEDED_SALAD = 10;
    private static int NEEDED_BREAD = 2;
    private static int NEEDED_BACON = 1;

    private final LoggingAdapter LOG = Logging.getLogger(context().system(), this);
    private int bread, bacon, salad; 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if(message instanceof Bacon){
            bacon ++;
        }
        else if(message instanceof BreadRoll){
            bread ++;
        }
        else if(message instanceof Salad){
            salad ++;
        }

        if (salad >= NEEDED_SALAD && bread >= NEEDED_BREAD && bacon >= NEEDED_BACON) {
            salad -= NEEDED_SALAD;
            bread -= NEEDED_BREAD;
            bacon -= NEEDED_BACON;

            // and sends message to (or spawns) another actor
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Burger message contains instances of the other objects Bacon, BreadRoll, Salad etc so I would need to keep three lists. I am not sure of the memory impact of this. If I keep receiving millions of Bacon instances (but not enough bread rolls) then presumably I am using up that much memory right? A better strategy would be to prepare a burger in another Actor/Thread while the main receiver accumulates these objects perhaps in a bounded buffer type entity?

Comment: yes, if it receives millions of Bacon messages - and you need to store all of them - it will sooner or later throw an OutOfMemory exception while adding the message to the list. A bounded buffer could be a solution if you don't care about loosing messages; otherwise you could setup a cluster, sized accordingly to the expected volume of messages, so that every instance of the actor will receive only a fraction of the total messages..

Comment: @CalmStorm If you need to keep references to all the bacon even if you may potentially never be given a bread roll, no amount of thread or any trickery will save you from an OOME. And that's irrespective of Akka, or even programming language, it's a simple fact of computing.